# Collision Detection Not Working for Sprites in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I have recently tried to upgrade the code for my game I am working on by changing my basic `rect` and images to the more advanced `Class` system. However, I seem to be having trouble with my collision detection, where when I tell my sprite `hg` to stop falling when colliding with `floor` (or any inputted `box`) it doesn't detect, but the script is running, so I know that the syntax isn't wrong. What am I doing wrong?
Here is what I believe is enough code to help you and the two pictures you will need (tell me if you need more info):

```
######## basic setup
import pygame, sys, time, random, threading, tkinter, ctypes
from threading import Timer
from pygame.locals import *
from tkinter import *
pygame.init()
WINDOWHEIGHT = 720
WINDOWWIDTH = 1280
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Hitman Grandma | vB1.0 (prealpha)')
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
black = (0,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
cyan = (0,255,255)
lightgrey = (198,198,198)
windowSurface.fill(lightgrey)
pygame.display.update()
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
########## variables
level = 0
touching = False
global x_speed
x_speed = 0
y_speed = 0
leftallowed = True
rightallowed = True
hgturnright = True
hgjumpallowed = True
########### the grandma d'awesome murder sorts
hgimage = pygame.image.load('hgfinal.png')
hgimage.convert_alpha()
class HG(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,image):
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y       
    def draw(self):
        windowSurface.blit(self.image,(self.x,self.y))
    def move(self):
        self.x += x_speed
        self.y += y_speed
    def topcollide(self,box):
        if not self.rect.colliderect(box.rect):
            global y_speed
            if y_speed < 20:
                y_speed += 1
            elif y_speed == 20:
                y_speed = 20
            print('shhoooo')
        elif self.rect.colliderect(box.rect):
            y_speed = 0
            print('flop')
hg = HG(0,0,hgimage)
########### land and boundary
lands = pygame.image.load('hgland1.png')
floorland = pygame.transform.scale(lands,(1280,50))
sideedge = pygame.Rect(0,0,1,720),pygame.Rect(1279,0,1,720)
topedge = pygame.Rect(0,0,1280,1)
class Floor(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,image):
        self.image = image
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
    def draw(self):
        windowSurface.blit(self.image,(self.x,self.y))
class Ground(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,image):
        self.image = image
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    def draw(self):
        windowSurface.blit(self.image,(self.x,self.y))
floor = Floor(0,670,floorland)
########### WHILE
while True:
########### background
    windowSurface.fill(lightgrey)
########### hg movement
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_LEFT and hg.x > 0 and leftallowed:
                    x_speed = -4
                    hgturnright = False
                if event.key == K_RIGHT and (hg.x + 36) < WINDOWWIDTH and rightallowed:
                    x_speed = 4
                    hgturnright = True
                if event.key == K_UP and hgjumpallowed:
                    y_speed = -17
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                x_speed = 0
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                x_speed = 0
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
########### ctrl+q
            if event.key == K_q and pygame.key.get_mods() & pygame.KMOD_CTRL:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
                exit
########### [x]
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
                exit
########### drawing and .move()
    floor.draw()
    hg.draw()
    hg.move()
    hg.topcollide(floor)
########### technicals
    pygame.display.update()
    mainClock.tick(40)
```

[image: character picture]
[image: floor picture]

Comment: BTW: instead `if not colliderect(): elif colliderect():` you can do `if not colliderect(): else:` becuse you don't have to check the same `colliderect()` two times.

Comment: use `print()` to check values in variables and which part of code is executed - it helps to find problem.

Comment: Yes, if something goes wrong with the collision detection, it usually helps to print the `rect`s of the involved objects.

Comment: Also, hitman grandma is hilarious. XD

Comment: Thanks @skrx, I am quite proud of her.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to update the position of the rect of the `HG` instance (`rect.topleft` or `rect.center`), because it's used for the collision detection:

```
class HG(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y,image):
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(x, y))
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def move(self):
        self.x += x_speed
        self.y += y_speed
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x, self.y)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! You have answered my questions before and you are always right! I can't believe I didn't think about not updating my `rect` position.